# Vb Compile Error expected: list separator or )

Tags: vb6

Line of code is:

```
BreakDown(Full As String, FName As String, PName As String, Ext As String) As Integer
```

took this from a tutorial so not sure what I'm doing wrong :/

thats a new function if it isn't obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I'm reading, the line of code is:

```
BreakDown(Full As String, FName As String, PName As String, Ext As String) As Integer
```

That should be:

```
Function BreakDown(Full As String, FName As String, PName As String, Ext As String) As Integer
```

Perhaps with a modifier before the word `Function`, such as `Private` or `Public`. When the function code is complete, make sure you also have this line:

```
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks bad combo of my retardation mixed with a missing word in a tutorial=unnecessary question on stackoverflow